# Preventing ng build from editing index.html, Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm building an Angular (4) Project, in which I seldom use `ng serve`, instead I compile the typescript and bundle the js using `ng build`, debug using else where.

`ng build` thankfully adds refs to bundles js files in the `dist` directory.

These following lines are auto generated and added to `index.html` by angular-cli when I execute `ng build`

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/inline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/styles.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

But here is the bad part. These lines are ***added*** to index.html everytime I call `ng build`. Is there any way to turn off the automated addition of references to the html. Its not a major problem, but would be nice to know a way to turn it off in the config.

Comment: not that I am aware of. Why would you not want those files to be added?

Comment: You can try putting "exclude": [ "index.html" ] in your .angular-cli.json

Comment: Its good that it added them once. But it adds the files everytime I call `ng build`. Thus I'll be including the scripts multiple times, for every build, in the index.html.

Comment: odd, this shouldn't be the case. The only thing I can think of is your output directory is the same as your source directory. What do you have as your "outDir" and "root" in the .angular-cli.json?

Comment: It shouldn't be concatinating the scripts, just adding the most recently bundled code for your Angular app.

Comment: My `outdir` is set to the default `dist` directory and `root` is set `src` and `index` is set to `..\index.html`. Only the `index` is not in its default place.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. `ng build --watch` would create an infinite loop as it constantly rebuilt itself responding to its own changes to `index.html`

Simply changing the `outdir` to `../dist` and referencing the files in that location sorted the issue for me.